# Same model for View and PartialView in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am having 2 functionalities Load and Edit. The records are loaded in the `WebGrid` and for edit i'm using popup. But for both functions i'm using the same Model. This is where i'm getting error.

When the records are loaded it works fine, when i use edit it works fine, but when i try to save the edits and return the `model` i'm getting error.

//MainView

```
@model AdhiaRecruitment.Models.CandidateDetailsModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CandidateDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    <style type="text/css">
        .grid
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
}
<h2>
    CandidateDetails</h2>
<div style="padding: 7px 0;">
    <input type="button" value="Add New Product" onclick="OpenCreatePopup()" />
</div>
<div style="width: 100%;">
    @{
        string template = string.Format("<text><img src='/img/edit.png' title='Edit' onclick='EditProduct({0})' /><img src='/img/delete.png' title='Delete' onclick='DeleteProduct({0})' /></text>", Model.CDId);

        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.LoadAllCandidateDetails());
        @grid.GetHtml(
         tableStyle: "grid",
         fillEmptyRows: false,
         headerStyle: "gvHeading",
         alternatingRowStyle: "gvAlternateRow",
         rowStyle: "gvRow",
         footerStyle: "gvFooter",

         mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
         firstText: "<< First",
         previousText: "< Prev",
         nextText: "Next >",
         lastText: "Last >>",
         columns: new[] {
         grid.Column("CDId", "ID"), 
         grid.Column("Name", "Name"),   
         grid.Column("Gender", "Gender"),                        
         grid.Column("", header: "Actions", canSort:false,
            format: @<text>
        @Html.Raw("<img src='/Images/edit-icon.png' alt='Edit' title='Edit' onclick='EditProduct(" + item.CDId + ")'  />")
        @Html.Raw("<img src='/Images/delete-icon.png' alt='Delete' title='Delete' onclick='DeleteProduct(" + item.CDId + ")'  />")
        </text>
        )    

     })    
    }
</div>
<div id="DivToAppendPartialView">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var ph = $("#DivToAppendPartialView");
        ph.dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 560,
            height: 560,
            title: "Edit Candidate",
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false
        });

    function EditProduct(cid) {

        ph.load("/CandidateDetails/EditCandidateDetails?candidateid=" + cid, function () {
            ph.dialog('open');

        });
    }
</script>
```

//Edit View

```
 @model AdhiaRecruitment.Models.CandidateDetailsModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>CandidateDetailsModel</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
             @*  # @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CDId)*@
               @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CDId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, Model.GenderList(),"--Select--")
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Gender, "Gender field is required")
        </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

//Model

```
public class CandidateDetailsModel
    {

        public int CDId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide name!")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name is too long!")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select gender!")]
        [Display(Name = "Gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

   public SelectList GenderList()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> lstGender = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Male" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Female" },
            };

            var selected = lstGender.Where(x => x.Text == Gender).First();
            Gender = selected.Value;

            return new SelectList(lstGender, "Value", "Text", Gender);
        }

  public List<CandidateDetails> LoadAllCandidateDetails()
        {
            List<CandidateDetails> lstCandidateDetails = new List<CandidateDetails>();

            CandidateServiceClient csClient = new CandidateServiceClient();
            lstCandidateDetails = csClient.LoadAllCandidateDetails();

            return lstCandidateDetails;
        }

 public int SaveCandidateDetails(CandidateDetails cdDetails)
        {
            int result = 0;

            CandidateServiceClient csClient = new CandidateServiceClient();
            result = csClient.SaveCandidateDetails(cdDetails);

            return result;
        }
```

//Controller

```
public class CandidateDetailsController : Controller
    {
        //  
        // GET: /Candidate/

        public ActionResult CandidateDetails()
        {
            return View(new CandidateDetailsModel());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult EditCandidateDetails(int candidateId)
        {
            CandidateDetailsModel cdSingle = new CandidateDetailsModel();

            CandidateDetails cdModel = cdSingle.LoadAllCandidateDetails().Where(x => x.CDId == candidateId).FirstOrDefault();

            cdSingle.CDId = cdModel.CDId;
            cdSingle.Name = cdModel.Name;
            cdSingle.Gender = cdModel.Gender;

            return PartialView(cdSingle);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult EditCandidateDetails(CandidateDetails cdDTO)
        {
            CandidateDetailsModel cdModel = new CandidateDetailsModel();

            CandidateDetails cdSingle = new CandidateDetails();

            cdSingle.CDId = cdDTO.CDId;
            cdSingle.Name = cdDTO.Name;
            cdSingle.Gender = cdDTO.Gender;

            cdModel.SaveCandidateDetails(cdSingle);           

            return View(cdModel);
        }

    }
```

After clicking save the `model` is loaded and when the `GenderList` is loading its throwing me the null error.

I'm not sure the process for `MVC` i have written is right. Do i have to create a separate `model` for Edit? If yes, For example if i have some 15 Edit functionalities in my application then i have to create 30 models??

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Edit Partial View you do not have a gender dropdown menu so when model binding happens on the Controller method, gender is always going to be `null`.

If you do not want the user to change/edit gender then you can use a hidden field to send the current gender back to the server.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Gender)
```

If you want to make gender editable then you will need a dropdown menu.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, Model.GenderList())
```

EDIT:
To solve the null Gender problem just put a null check and default it like so:

```
Gender = Gender == null ? "male" : Gender; //Set default if null
var selected = lstGender.Where(x => x.Text == Gender).First();
            Gender = selected.Value;
```

Comment: It was there. Sorry!!! Missed it. My question is can i use same model for both the funtions? If yes/no how? Error is from model.

Comment: there are no null checks on this line: `var selected = lstGender.Where(x => x.Text == Gender).First();`
It would be hard to figure out which part is causing the null exception. If Gender is null then it would cause a problem. If gender does not match anything then `.First()` is going to throw null. You could try `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: To answer your question specifically you can use the same model.

Comment: My gender is null. So is that validation is the only way that i can get rid off this error? or do i have any changes in the model/controller/view?